# Linq - Select a particular column

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

In Table I have 5 columns :- name, age, dob, doj, entrydate.

```
string column = 'dob'; // This is dynamic

var data = ctx.tblTable
                    .Where(e => e.Id == Id && e.Name == name)
                    .Select(e => column).SingleOrDefault();
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work. How to select a particular column in linq.

Comment: I don't know for sure, but I think you'll have to pull the full row down, then use reflection to grab the individual column. I like to think there's a better way, but that's the best one I know of.

Comment: Perhaps this answer can help you too: http://stackoverflow.com/a/233505/858757

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
string column = 'dob'; // This is dynamic

var data = ctx.tblTable
                    .Where(e => e.Id == Id && e.Name == name)
                    .ToList()
                    .Select(e => GetPropValue(e, column))
                    .FirstOrDefault();


public object GetPropValue(object obj, string propName)
{
     return obj.GetType().GetProperty(propName).GetValue(obj, null);
}
```

Comment: I get this Error :- `{"LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Object GetPropValue(System.Object, System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression."}`

Comment: This will pull the entire table in memory first

Comment: @jeroenh No. It will pull only the table entries matching query **Where(e => e.Id == Id && e.Name == name)**

Answer (score 4):

Use as

```
var data = ctx.tblTable
                .Where(e => e.Id == Id && e.Name == name)
                .SingleOrDefault().ColumnName;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
string column = 'dob';
var data = ctx.tblTable
                .Where(e => e.Id == Id && e.Name == name)
                .Select(e = > e.GetType().GetProperty(column).GetValue(e,null));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a SQL query instead? I assume that you are using Entity Framework. In that case use:

```
var columnValues = ctx.Database
         .SqlQuery<string>("SELECT " + column + " FROM tblTable WHERE Id = " + Id + " AND Name = '" + name + "'").ToList();
```

And make sure that `column`, `Id` and `name` do not allow SQL injection or unwanted values. You could do that with parametrized queries.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class TestClass
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public DateTime Dob { get; set; }

        public void YourMethod()
        {
            List<TestClass> temp = new List<TestClass>();

            var x = from xyz in temp
                    where xyz.Name == "Name" && xyz.Id == new Guid()
                    select xyz.Dob;
        }
    }
```